# Как сделать navigationDrawer как в мобильном приложении mail.ru?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!
В приложении почта mail.ru есть выдвижное боковое меню, при нажатии на "сендвич" боковое меню появляется и сдвигает контент. Как добиться такого результата?
Обычно боковое меню выдвигается поверх контента. Вот и возник вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

не знаком с приложением mail.ru, но по описанию подходит [SlidingPaneLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html). Эта панель как раз сдвигает контент.